# Bind Click function with parameter

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

In `MVVM Cross` for Android in Xamarin Studio,

I can write this in my .axml file to bind a click function to a button:

```
local:MvxBind="Click SendMessage"
```

`SendMessage` is a public method on the MvxViewModel with the signature

```
public void SendMessage() 
{
//do stuff
}
```

However, I want to do something like like this,

```
local:MvxBind="Click SendMessage param1: foo, param2: bar"
```

which should call the method underneath with a signature like this,

```
public void SendMessage(T foo, T bar) 
{
//do stuff
}
```

where foo and bar might be the current selected item, or the object represented in a particular row of a table etc.

I can't see anywhere that points towards how to do this, and I am hoping that it is a native functionality! Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding engine allows you to use either `ICommand` instances or `public void` methods. The latter only works if you also install the [NuGet package MethodBinding](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.MethodBinding/4.0.0-beta1).

As for the amount of parameters supported, it boils down to a single argument, which should correspond to the `ViewModel` bound to the item in the ListView.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an ICommand instead of a void to execute your code, here you can paas one parameter.

An other option is to bind the parameters you need to objects and access these objects in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Being a bit illiteracy with the exact functionality in xamarin studio, I would like to suggest a general different approach:

How about letting the controls on your View set a class wide property `SelectedItem` when they're selected, that could then be accessed by the buttons method when it's clicked?

Comment: Thanks for your answer M463. 

That could work in some circumstances and may well be the route I go if there really isn't another way to do this. However it feels like a lot of overhead and a bunch of extra coding for something that seems like pretty basic functionality (This kind of thing is supported natively in AngularJs and Knockout for instance, I know that JS is not C sharp, but the parallels in terms of what the frameworks are trying to provide are there).